# if condition in javascript not working on null value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

what i am trying to do is, if text box have some value page should move to center div, when text box is empty page should stay on start position.

in my code page always goes to second div.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mattii/po981sbe/25/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ((document.getElementById("textbox").value != null)) {

    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#what').offset().top
    }, 'slow');

  }

});
```

```css
div {
  height: 900px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textbox" />
<div id="mydiv">DATA FOR SAMPLE 1</div>
<div id="what">SAMPLE DATA</div>
```

Comment: There is no way a textbox value will be null in modern browsers. In IE4 or so it would be null if the value attribute was not specified on the tag

Comment: `value` is always an empty string if it's not filled in. Even if the attribute is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test for the length of the trimmed value

That can handle spaces

NOTE the value of "0" is truthy

```js
$(function() { // on page load
  if ($("#textbox").val().trim().length > 0) { // === 0 when empty
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#what').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 900px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textbox" value="" />
<div id="mydiv">DATA FOR SAMPLE 1</div>
<div id="what">SAMPLE DATA</div>
```

Comment: i want to run it automatically when page loads

Comment: My code runs automatically on page load, I  only removed unnecessary code

Comment: if i put no value in text box, $(function() {
  if ($("#textbox").val().trim().length < 0) {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
   alert("dd");
  }
}); why this isn't working

Comment: because it is === 0 when empty

Answer (score 0):

Remove the camparison with null:

```
if (document.getElementById("textbox").value !== '') {

    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#what').offset().top
    }, 'slow');

  }
```

Comment: @mplungjan, I didn't knew "0" is false as well. I thought integer 0 is false.

Comment: [`"0"` is indeed truthy](https://jsbin.com/dibujaceqa/edit?js,console). Also see [the JS equality table](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/) - go to the `if ()` tab.

Comment: This is actually ok as long as there are no spaces in the field

Answer (score 0):

Change `!= null` to `!==''`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ((document.getElementById("textbox").value !== '')) {

    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#what').offset().top
    }, 'slow');

  }

});
```

```css
div {
  height: 900px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textbox" />
<div id="mydiv">DATA FOR SAMPLE 1</div>
<div id="what">SAMPLE DATA</div>
```